# Elasticsearch Snapshot failing as partial because of 2 new nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I am relatively new to Elasticsearch. I have a 6 nodes cluster where 2 nodes are newly added. When I am trying to take snapshot of any index it is failing for the shards in the new nodes.
I am using ElasticSearch 7.9.2 and all the plugins like azure, repository-s3 are already installed on the VM.

My elasticsearch.yml file has

```
s3.client.default.endpoint: {s3_Ip}
s3.client.default.protocol: http
s3.client.default.signer_override: S3SignerType
# aws config ends
```

Just like all other nodes. Still I am getting

> "reason": "IndexShardSnapshotFailedException[failed to list blobs]; nested: IOException[Exception when listing blobs by prefix [index-]]; nested: SdkClientException[Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]; nested: SocketTimeoutException[Connect timed out]",
> "node_id": "GrmPnp8_Qhax6Ow1y9TYeA",
> "status": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"

By my assumption S3 is unable to connect to the nodes or vice-versa.
Is there anything I need to setup?

Comment: In my opinion, it's the other way around, i.e. (some of) the nodes cannot connect to S3. So make sure that ALL nodes have the exact same `s3.client` configuration. Also make sure that anything secret (aws access/secret keys) stored in secret keystores are present in each node's keystore

Comment: @Val I am trying to add the settings but could not add them to elasticsearch.yml file. Based on what I read they need to be added to the keystore file. 
Please let me know where I can find that file